# Why does GCC speak about a dependent base?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a continuation of [When is a class member visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633612/when-is-a-class-member-visible)

After making the class compile with GCC by moving the declaration of `pk_` to the beginning, I tried to use it:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

using from_type = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

template<typename PK, size_t N>
struct pf {
public:
    PK pk_;

    pf(from_type const& a, std::string const& pkn) noexcept(noexcept(fill(pk_, std::string{})))
    : map_(a) // GCC 4.8 requires ()s for references
    , pk_{ [&]{ fill(pk_, pkn); return pk_; }() }
    {
    }

    template<typename prop_t>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_integral<typename std::decay<prop_t>::type>::value,
        pf<PK, N>>::type const&
    fill(prop_t& , std::string const& , prop_t  = 0) const noexcept(false);

    pf<PK, N> const&
    fill(std::string& , std::string const&) const noexcept;
protected:
    from_type const& map_;
    uint32_t aieee;

};

std::string k;
from_type m;

int i;
std::string s;

static_assert(!noexcept(pf<int        , 42>{m, k}), "int could throw");
static_assert( noexcept(pf<std::string, 17>{m, k}), "string shouldn't throw");
```

clang 4.0, 6.0 and trunk again compiled the program.

GCC was still not happy:

```
$ g++-99 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wformat=2 -std=c++14 pf.cpp
pf.cpp: In instantiation of ‘pf<PK, N>::pf(const from_type&, const string&) [with PK = int; long unsigned int N = 42; from_type = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
pf.cpp:38:49:   required from here
pf.cpp:12:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘fill(int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)’
   12 |     pf(from_type const& a, std::string const& pkn) noexcept(noexcept(fill(pk_, std::string{})))
      |                                                                      ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/string:40,
                 from pf.cpp:1:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:742:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp> void std::fill(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&)’
  742 |     fill(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, const _Tp& __value)
      |     ^~~~
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:742:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
pf.cpp:12:74: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_ForwardIterator’ (‘int’ and ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’)
   12 |     pf(from_type const& a, std::string const& pkn) noexcept(noexcept(fill(pk_, std::string{})))
      |                                                                      ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pf.cpp: In instantiation of ‘pf<PK, N>::pf(const from_type&, const string&) [with PK = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; long unsigned int N = 17; from_type = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
pf.cpp:39:49:   required from here
pf.cpp:12:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘fill(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)’
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/string:40,
                 from pf.cpp:1:
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:742:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp> void std::fill(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&)’
  742 |     fill(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, const _Tp& __value)
      |     ^~~~
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:742:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
pf.cpp:12:74: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
   12 |     pf(from_type const& a, std::string const& pkn) noexcept(noexcept(fill(pk_, std::string{})))
      |                                                                      ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pf.cpp:39:16: error: static assertion failed: string shouldn't throw
   39 | static_assert( noexcept(pf<std::string, 17>{m, k}), "string shouldn't throw");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This was confusing (who said anything about iterators?) until I saw the answer to my first question. The compiler couldn't see the `fill` members, so it tried the only `fill` method available to it: the one from `<algorithm>`, which was accidentally included via

```
. /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/string
.. /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h
... /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h
```

So I renamed the `fill` members to `fillz` (including the one in the `noexcept` operator), which resulted in:

```
$ g++-99 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wformat=2 -std=c++14 pf.cpp
pf.cpp: In instantiation of ‘pf<PK, N>::pf(const from_type&, const string&) [with PK = int; long unsigned int N = 42; from_type = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
pf.cpp:38:49:   required from here
pf.cpp:12:75: error: ‘fillz’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
   12 |     pf(from_type const& a, std::string const& pkn) noexcept(noexcept(fillz(pk_, std::string{})))
      |                                                                      ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pf.cpp:12:75: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pf<int, 42>’ are not found by unqualified lookup
pf.cpp:12:75: note: use ‘pf::fillz’ instead
pf.cpp:12:75: error: cannot call member function ‘const typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<prop_t>::type>::value, pf<PK, N> >::type& pf<PK, N>::fillz(prop_t&, const string&, prop_t) const [with prop_t = int; PK = int; long unsigned int N = 42; typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<prop_t>::type>::value, pf<PK, N> >::type = pf<int, 42>; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ without object
pf.cpp: In instantiation of ‘pf<PK, N>::pf(const from_type&, const string&) [with PK = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; long unsigned int N = 17; from_type = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
pf.cpp:39:49:   required from here
pf.cpp:12:75: error: ‘fillz’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
pf.cpp:12:75: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pf<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 17>’ are not found by unqualified lookup
pf.cpp:12:75: note: use ‘pf::fillz’ instead
pf.cpp:12:75: error: cannot call member function ‘const pf<PK, N>& pf<PK, N>::fillz(std::string&, const string&) const [with PK = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; long unsigned int N = 17; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ without object
pf.cpp:39:16: error: static assertion failed: string shouldn't throw
   39 | static_assert( noexcept(pf<std::string, 17>{m, k}), "string shouldn't throw");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Obviously GCC can still not see the member (now named `fillz`), but why does it complain about dependent bases? Struct `pf` has nothing to do with inheritance. Could it be because this kind of visibility problem comes up most often with dependent bases?

In the end, the correct usage turned out to be:

```
noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<pf&>().fill(std::declval<PK&>(), std::string{})))
```

Comment: I think your guess is correct. It's just a note about one possible reason for this kind of error. It doesn't mean your specific example fails because of this reason.

Comment: `std::declval<pf&>()`, using an rvalue there seems wrong.

Comment: gcc says about dependent base because of ADL. It uses std::basic_string scope and its base scopes for lookup.

Comment: As an aside, if you put `fill` *before* the constructor, you get another interesting error: "cannot call fill without object".

Comment: Are you sure your fix is correct? https://ideone.com/0BBmqz

Comment: Or just `noexcept(this->fill(this->pk_, pkn))` to avoid repeating yourself and just do the right thing.

Comment: @Oktalist this doesn't compile with gcc for the exact same reason the original code fails.

Comment: @n.m. works for me https://godbolt.org/z/H3r5Zh

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  `std::declval<pf>()` is an rvalue reference, but `std::declval<pf&>()` is an lvalue reference (which is needed for the first argument of `fill`).

Comment: @Oktalist doesn't work in a minimal example https://ideone.com/ZEiH7m.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet to be more clear: `std::declval<pf>().fill` seems wrong -- should be `std::declval<pf&>().fill`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, Thanks, I meant to put in `std::declval<pf&>()` but failed at copy-paste :(

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this seems like it could be more than one bug in GCC.

(All standard quotes are from C++14, as you are compiling with `-std=c++14`. All bold is added.)

> [basic.scope.class]¶1
>
> **The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists** [...] also of all function bodies, default arguments, ***exception-specifications***, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* of non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested classes).

So in the `noexcept` clause of a member function declaration, all members of the class are in scope regardless of the order in which they are declared.

But this isn't enough to convince ourselves that your code is well-formed. We are in a class template, so next we need to consider two-phase lookup:

> [temp.dep]¶1
>
> In an expression of the form:
>
> > *postfix-expression* `(` *expression-listopt* `)`
>
> where the *postfix-expression* is an *unqualified-id*, **the *unqualified-id* denotes a *dependent name* if**
>
> - (1.1) any of the expressions in the *expression-list* is a pack expansion,
> - (1.2) **any of the expressions in the *expression-list* is a type-dependent expression**, or
> - (1.3) if the *unqualified-id* is a *template-id* in which any of the template arguments depends on a template parameter.
>
> Such names are unbound and are looked up at the point of the template instantiation in both the context of the template definition and the context of the point of instantiation.

Therefore `fill` is a dependent name in `fill(pk_, std::string{})` because `pk_` is type-dependent, so `fill` will be looked up when the template is instantiated, both in the context of the template itself and the point where it was instantiated. Due to ADL and the fact that one of the arguments is `std::string`, the `std` namespace is included in the lookup, leading to the messages about `std::fill`. But lookup should also find the member function `fill`, as previously discussed.

Now we have convinced ourselves that the code is well-formed. We could simply file a bug and move on. But let's keep digging to see how well we understand what's happening.

---

> [temp.dep]¶3
>
> In the definition of a class or class template, **if a base class depends on a *template-parameter*, the base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup** either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

The error messages seem to indicate that GCC is (wrongly) considering the enclosing class of `fill` to be a dependent base of `fill`, and hence applying the wording of [temp.dep]¶3.

The usual way to refer to names in dependent bases is to refer to them through a *qualified-id* (e.g. `pf::fill`) or a class member access expression (e.g. `this->fill`). So what happens when we try either of these approaches as a workaround?

Writing `this->fill` seems to work in your example code, but as noted by @n.m. in the comments, this is brittle and doesn't work in a more minimal example, yielding the error "invalid use of 'this' at top level".

Writing `pf::fill` yields the error "cannot call member function without object". This is probably for the same reason that `this->fill` failed: if `this` is invalid then it must also be invalid to transform an *id-expression* into a implicit member access expression.

> [expr.prim.general]/3
>
> If a declaration declares **a member function** or member function template **of a class `X`, the expression `this` is** a prvalue of type "pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`" **between the optional *cv-qualifer-seq* and the end of the *function-definition***, *member-declarator*, or *declarator*.

So `this` is valid to appear in an *exception-specification* and GCC is wrong to reject it, and this looks on the face of it to be a bug separate from the one we already diagnosed. This last one is already known as [52869](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52869), but the testcase submitted with the bugfix failed to exercise the case in which the `noexcept` appears before the declaration of the member function it refers to, as in your case. So it's unclear whether your first set of errors are really part of the same bug.